I want to make sure a logic in QCP run only when Save Or Calculate Button Clicked on QLE
I am working with Salesforce CPQ and I have a requirement to ensure that my QCP (Quote Calculator Plugin) logic only runs when the user clicks the 'Save' or 'Calculate' buttons on the QLE (Quote Line Editor) page. The issue is that the QCP logic also gets triggered by server-side processes, such as when a record is updated via a trigger or workflow rule.
I have attempted to detect the browser environment (using window or document) to determine if the logic was initiated by a button click, but since QCP always runs on the server, this approach does not work.
Is there any way in Salesforce CPQ to:
Detect if the QCP was triggered specifically by the Save or Calculate button click in the UI?
What is the best practice to achieve this in Salesforce CPQ? Any help or code samples would be greatly appreciated.

export function onBeforeCalculate(quote, lines, conn, context)
{
// Check if QCP is invoked due to a button click on the Quote Line Editor
if (context.mode === 'EditLines')
{
}
